# I’m using (gulp) HTML,sass,js . How can I upload it to my online seever?

Tags: server, upload, gulp

I am using Gulp, and I have build one admin template just for practice purpose. I'm searching on Google and YouTube but I didn’t find any solution.

Am I able to upload this website to my server? If I remove node modules and then upload it to the server, will it work?

[image: No Image Description Provided]